# Une bonne traduction pour « awesome »

Tags: traduction, anglais, interjections

On trouve facilement des équivalents pour *awesome*, le [wiktionnaire](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/en/wiki/awesome) par exemple propose *magnifique* ou *génial*. Ces mots conviennent bien pour un emploi en tant adjectif du type *This gig was awesome !*, mais je n'arrive pas à trouver d'équivalent pour l'emploi comme interjection.

> « I have the tickets for *The Wall*  !
>
> — Awesome !»

Je trouve *génial* un peu faible pour cet emploi.

**Edit** : Quand je dis *trop faible* je veux dire *je ne me vois pas le hurler de joie spontanément*. Si vous êtes déjà allé à un concert où le *frontman* hurle **AWESOME!** vous devriez comprendre :)

Comment: Bof, je trouve que *génial* correspond très bien.

Comment: Des goûts et des couleurs...

Comment: A few years after, I feel the urge of adding this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rYT0YvQ3hs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Super! [Mortel!](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mortel) [Chouette!](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chouette) [Formidable!](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/formidable) [Cool](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cool)! Trop Cool! Trop Fort! Méga! ou n'importe quelle combinaison:

> Trop hyper-méga-génial de la mort qui tue!

(Ou pas)

Comment: +1 I was about to submit "Trop cool" and "Trop fort", but you beat me to the punch.

Comment: @Zoot Génial! ... eerm, I mean, sorry!

Comment: C'est pas grave.

Comment: *Mortel* n'est pas du meilleur goût, mais c'est le plus proche, je pense.

Comment: +1 pour la mort qui tue (et qui se rit de nous, aussi).

Comment: Si je suis avec des amis très proche je dirais. "Hey, j'ai chopé des tickets pour The Wall" Une "putain" de tuerie ! [PS: i don't mean to be rude :) ]

Answer (score 22):

excellent ! génial ! fabuleux ! énorme ! trop d'la balle !

Comment: Je trouve qu'énorme est le plus proche.

Comment: Je préfère _excellent_ - http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Montgomery_Burns

Comment: "trop d'la balle" ? un peu trop argotique non?

Comment: @Nikko *Awesome* aussi, ce me semble :)

Comment: as usual with such words, it's really a matter of era: sometimes to the year...

Answer (score 7):

Fantastique !  Génial !  Formidable !

Answer (score 4):

Je pense que formidable est très proche d'awesome parce que dans un sens (vieilli) il signifie effrayant, redoutable, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Je suggère **époustouflant** comme réponse. Il y a l'idée de surprise dans *awesome*.

Comment: Mais ça ressemble plus à de la littérature et moins à une interjection.

Comment: Oui, pour le frontman du concert là... on est au concert d'Henri Dès.

Answer (score 1):

Voici d'autres traductions qui me viennent à l'esprit :

- Ca déchire !
- Trop bon !
- Merveilleux !
- Génialissime !
- Topissime ! (mon préféré)

Answer (score 0):

Gueuler “awesome” fait quand même un peu adolescent (plus ou moins attardé). Je vais donc piocher dans le sociolecte parlé par ma cousine :

> « Chan-mé ! » « Frais ! »

Comment: Ca me fait penser qu'il y a aussi _C'est violent!_ voire _brutal_

Comment: -1 pour la condescendance, un peu. (Outre que je n'ai jamais entendu quoi que ce soit qui ressemble à ce sociolecte.)

Comment: Dans la même branche, probablement local pour certains : *Emeute!*, *Boucherie!*, *Carnage!*, *Tuerie!*, *Ca déchire!*, *Ca dépote!*, *D'la balle!* (1 bouquet garni à celui qui trouvera un éventuel champ sémantique)

Answer (score 0):

Et sans oublier :

- *Terrible !* qui est positif dans ce contexte, contrairemant à l'anglais où il est toujours péjoratif.
- *Top !*

Answer (score -1):

- Épatant!
- Éclatant!
- Superbe!

Comment: _Éclatant_? Je sais qu'on va à un concert pour s'éclater, mais je ne l'avais jamais entendu en interjection.

Comment: Ah si, quelquefois, mais pas dans ce contexte. "Je reviens du spectacle, c'était éclatant !" - mais là, ça veut dire "à mourir de rire".

Comment: @Shlublu : Ça reste un adjectif, plus qu'une interjection.